# Swift 2 finding variable name from value

Tags: swift, variables

I have this function that finds the closest location of some pre determined locations to a current location. I get the value as a result but what I want is the name. In this example it would be "Larkspur"

```
 let lat = 37.941053
let long = -122.483915


let locationLarkspur = CLLocation(latitude: 37.944804, longitude: -122.509066)
let locationSaulsalito = CLLocation(latitude: 37.856315, longitude: -122.478723)
let locationSanFrancisco = CLLocation(latitude: 37.795346, longitude: -122.392711)
let locationFishermans = CLLocation(latitude: 37.809166, longitude: -122.412012)
let locationGiants = CLLocation(latitude: 37.778304, longitude: -122.387754)
let locationTiburon = CLLocation(latitude: 37.872928, longitude: -122.455806)
let locationVallejo = CLLocation(latitude: 38.100116, longitude: -122.262378)
let locationAlameda = CLLocation(latitude: 37.790633, longitude: -122.293910)
let locationHarborBay = CLLocation(latitude: 37.736799, longitude: -122.256810)
let locationJackLondon = CLLocation(latitude: 37.795287, longitude: -122.279601)
let locationSouthSF = CLLocation(latitude: 37.662428, longitude: -122.377791)
let locationCurrent = CLLocation(latitude:  lat, longitude:  long)

print(long)

let Larkspur = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationLarkspur)
let Saulsalito = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationSaulsalito)
let SanFrancisco = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationSanFrancisco)
let Fishermans = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationFishermans)
let Giants = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationGiants)
let Tiburon = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationTiburon)
let Vallejo = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationVallejo)
let Alameda = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationAlameda)
let HarborBay = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationHarborBay)
let JackLondon = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationJackLondon)
let SouthSF = locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationSouthSF)



let numbers = [Larkspur, Saulsalito, SanFrancisco, Fishermans, Giants, Tiburon, Vallejo, Alameda, HarborBay, JackLondon, SouthSF]

numbers.minElement()
numbers.maxElement()

let closest = numbers.minElement()

print(closest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a slightly different take using a custom structure to hold location info:

```
import CoreLocation

// Create a custom structure to hold place names, latitude, and longitude
struct Location {
    var name: String
    var latitude: Double
    var longitude: Double
}

let lat = 37.941053
let long = -122.483915

let locations: [Location] = [
    Location(name: "Larkspur", latitude: 37.944804, longitude: -122.509066),
    Location(name: "Saulsalito", latitude: 37.856315, longitude: -122.478723),
    Location(name: "SanFrancisco", latitude: 37.795346, longitude: -122.392711),
    Location(name: "Fishermans", latitude: 37.809166, longitude: -122.412012),
    Location(name: "Giants", latitude: 37.778304, longitude: -122.387754),
    Location(name: "Tiburon", latitude: 37.872928, longitude: -122.455806),
    Location(name: "Vallejo", latitude: 38.100116, longitude: -122.262378),
    Location(name: "Alameda", latitude: 37.790633, longitude: -122.293910),
    Location(name: "HarborBay", latitude: 37.736799, longitude: -122.256810),
    Location(name: "JackLondon", latitude: 37.795287, longitude: -122.279601),
    Location(name: "SouthSF", latitude: 37.662428, longitude: -122.377791)
]

let currentLocation = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: long)

// Use map to create an array of named tuple pairs with distance and location name
let distances:[(distance: Double, name: String)] = locations.map { (CLLocation(latitude: $0.latitude, longitude: $0.longitude).distanceFromLocation(currentLocation), $0.name) }

let closest = distances.minElement {$0.distance < $1.distance}!

print("Closest location is \(closest.name) at a distance of \(closest.distance)")
```

Comment: Good answer. Using a custom  `Location struct`  makes the code more readable and allows you to store data inside an `Array` instead of a `Dictionary`. Good choice.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an extension of the answer by `gfpacheco`.

The code is Functional Programming oriented.

### 1. Create a Dictionary where

- the `Key` is the name of the location (a `String`)
- the `Value` is position of the location (`CLLocation`)

like this:

```
let coordinates = [
    "Larkspur": CLLocation(latitude: 37.944804, longitude: -122.509066),
    "Saulsalito": CLLocation(latitude: 37.856315, longitude: -122.478723),
    "SanFrancisco": CLLocation(latitude: 37.795346, longitude: -122.392711),
    "Fishermans": CLLocation(latitude: 37.809166, longitude: -122.412012),
    "Giants": CLLocation(latitude: 37.778304, longitude: -122.387754),
    "Tiburon": CLLocation(latitude: 37.872928, longitude: -122.455806),
    "Vallejo": CLLocation(latitude: 38.100116, longitude: -122.262378),
    "Alameda": CLLocation(latitude: 37.790633, longitude: -122.293910),
    "HarborBay": CLLocation(latitude: 37.736799, longitude: -122.256810),
    "JackLondon": CLLocation(latitude: 37.795287, longitude: -122.279601),
    "SouthSF": CLLocation(latitude: 37.662428, longitude: -122.377791)
]
```

### 2. Define "here"

```
let here = CLLocation(latitude:  12.3, longitude:  12.3)
```

### 3. Create a new Dictionary of distances

```
let distances = coordinates.enumerate().reduce([String:CLLocationDistance]()) { (var accumulator, elm) -> [String:CLLocationDistance] in
    accumulator[elm.element.0] = elm.element.1.distanceFromLocation(here)
    return accumulator
}
```

### 4. Find the closest

```
let closest = distances.minElement { $0.1 < $1.1}?.0
```

Now `closest` does contain the name of the closest location.

Comment: Your `closest` calculation needs work.  It always returns `Alameda`.

Comment: Your closest calculation is getting the minimum key (always Alameda). You should be calculating the minimun value than returning it's key instead

Answer (score 0):

You should have a dict `[String:CLLocationDistance]` instead of an array, this way you can get the string value and the distance:

```
let distances = [
    "Larkspur": locationCurrent.distanceFromLocation(locationLarkspur)
    // ...
]
```

You'll have to rewrite your code to find the minimum distance, but it'll give you what you want.